# Building Blocks Tree Nodes Sorting

Tags: 2011

I am creating Building Blocks tree structure through Core Service, CMS automatically sort them alphabetically but i want to sort them according to the order i create them. Is there any way to sort them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tridion will always sort alphabetically in the CME. If you really need another order, you can either prefix your titles (e.g. 010_ItemName) or you will need to write a GUI extension to order them differently.

Comment: Yes i will use prefix approach, I am also trying to associate a metadata to my folder, I have created a test folder and associated the metadata and i got following XML [<Metadata>
            <folder-typexlink:href="tcm:4-143-1024"xlink:title="Folder">Folder</folder-type>
         </Metadata>] when i assign the same xml to my actual folder's metadata string property it gives error [Root element must be in namespace:] Is there any other way to associate a metadata schema to a folder?

Comment: uuid in your metadata schema must match, while assigning metadata xmlelement. This is the reason you are getting the error.

Comment: Consider creating a new question for these comments--they'd be useful as a separate Q&A. :-) Also, please accept this answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq to sort items based on Creation Date.

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData itemsFilter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
IEnumerable<IdentifiableObjectData> items = channel.GetList(buildingBlocksId, itemsFilter).OrderByDescending(o => o.VersionInfo.CreationDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Out of the box, you can sort folders using the `Modified` column in the Content Manager.** This would match your creation date before any changes.

Otherwise consider adding a column for Creation date if this is a frequent use case.

**Tip**: the business should have input into the directory structure as well as any changes to default ordering, especially for non-system folders. Sorting by name is a very common authoring convention. :-)